# Browser's restriction from angular web app

Tags: angular, security, web

I'm developing a web app with Angular. This web app, will be installed on some devices which belong to me. And this device will be exposed for show, exposure, ...

I want people use the app on the device, but I don't want them to do something else with the device. So my question is:

From my angular app, is this possible to do this kind of things:

- Lock the browser on fullscreen when I'm using the app.
- Prevent user to use shortcut such as alt + f4, f11, etc...

Comment: Are you looking to set up Kiosk mode?

Comment: Oh, never heard about kiosk mode, but after looking it, yes I would like something like that but implemented from the app, so I can disable/enable functionalities relative to current url, data in app, etc..